# Is it possible to view the maintenance plans created in SQL Server 2000 in SSMS 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

Is it possible to view the maintenance plans created in SQL Server 2000 (also running on the same SQL server 2000) in SQL 2005 Server Manangement Studio? I have the server added in my SSMS, but when I expand the Management folder, I don't see the Maintenance Plans folder like what I'd expect from a 2005 server.

For example, we have an optimization plan scheduled to run every week in SQL Server Agent and the command used to run this is: xp_sqlmaint N'-PlanID F7491D04-CDBA-496F-AE57-C2C5A3E3C8F8 (plus a bunch of options). I have no idea how to view this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL 2000 maintenance plans are just SQL Jobs with a bunch of parameters.  You can easily enough just look at the parameters which are passed to sqlmaint.

Comment: Thanks, mrdenny. Found the MSDN page for sqlmaint with its bunch of switches. By the way, big fan of your blogs!

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out. It's under Legacy->Database Maintenance Plans. Also all the plans, optimizations, integrity, trans log and complete backup are bunched up under one title.