# Database Maintenance Planner greyed out (disabled)

Tags: sql-server, maintenance

I have to look into some SQL Server 2000 maintenance plans, but Database Maintenance Planner option is greyed out in Tools menu of Enterprise Manager. SQL Server Agent seems enabled and running, because its icon has the green badge when I access the instance via a SQL Server 2005 SSMS.

Any hints?

Thank you

Comment: Any help? http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12584/3690

Comment: yes thank you: it seems that from the arguments passed to the SP one can infer all the actions performed in the plan.